# NSPredicate - fetching core data restricted to future dates

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I need to retrieve all `Booking` objects with `departDate` property set to current date or future date. My code is as below:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(departDate >= %@)", [NSDate date]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error;
bookings = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] retain];

NSLog(@"curernt date %@", [NSDate date]);

for (Booking *order in bookings) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:order.departDate]);
}
```

But the log shows:

```
2012-03-06 18:58:24.518 Airline[2201:207] curernt date 2012-03-06 13:28:24 +0000
2012-03-06 18:58:24.520 Airline[2201:207] 2012-03-06 12:37:59 +0000
2012-03-06 18:58:24.528 Airline[2201:207] 2012-03-05 12:55:50 +0000
2012-03-06 18:58:24.529 Airline[2201:207] 2012-03-08 12:55:50 +0000
2012-03-06 18:58:24.530 Airline[2201:207] 2012-03-02 13:07:33 +0000
2012-03-06 18:58:24.531 Airline[2201:207] 2012-04-06 13:13:53 +0000
2012-03-06 18:58:24.532 Airline[2201:207] 2012-01-06 13:13:53 +0000
```

All the objects are being retrieved as if there is no filters. Could some one please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data support dates directly as `NSDate`. You've mixing using `NSDate` and the date as *seconds since 1970*.

In your model, make sue `departDate` is set to be a "Date", then use

```
for (Booking *order in bookings) {
    NSLog(@"%@", order.departDate);
}
```

Comment: in my data model `departDate` is set as `Date`, but when I generate the `NSManagedObject` subclass, I checked the "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" and maybe because of that the `departData` is defined as `NSTimeInterval` in my class.. I will try to change only that variable type to `NSDate` and see if its working.

Comment: changing the datatype of `DepartDate` from NSTimeInterval to NSDate worked... :)